# Why can't I access my REST urls from my requirejs config

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to set up a REST url in my `requirejs` config.  Here is my config:

```
  require.config({
    config: {
      url: 'http://test.herokuapp.com'
    }
  });
```

I then try to access the url in my module:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';

  var Backbone = require('backbone');
  var url = module.config().url;

  var SessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: url + '/login'
  });
  return SessionModel;
});
```

I then fire up my app, and when I try to hit the url I get this error:

```
POST http://99.44.242.76:3000/app/undefined/login 404 (Not Found)
```

My `url` is undefined.  How do I access this piece of my config file in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`config`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig) setting works on a *per-module* basis. The `config` setting is an object which has for keys module names, and `module.config()` returns only the value associated with the name of the module that calls it. So you'd have to put your module name in your configuration:

```
require.config({
  config: {
    my_module: {
      url: 'http://test.herokuapp.com'
    }
  }
});
```

Where `my_module` should be the actual name of your module. Then the `url` setting will be available as `module.config().url` (which is what you are already using).

If you want the `url` setting to be available to all modules, one thing you can do is to create a module that merely exports its config. For instance, if I call this module `global`:

```
require.config({
  config: {
    global: {
      url: 'http://test.herokuapp.com'
    }
  }
});
```

Then `global.js` could contain something like:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';

  return module.config();
});
```

And then the module you had in your question could be something like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  'use strict';

  var global = require("global");
  var Backbone = require('backbone');

  var url = global.url;

  var SessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: url + '/login'
  });
  return SessionModel;
});
```

Comment: I know this is vague, but I copied your code and I am still getting undefined for the url.  Do you have any other ideas where I could of gotten it wrong?

Comment: I have two solutions in my answer. The first would make ``url`` available only to one module. The second would make ``url`` available to multiple modules. Which one did you use?

Comment: I used the 2nd one to make the `url` available to multiple modules.  I have the global set up in the config.  I created a `global.js` and when I get to the module using the `global.js` to get the `url` I get undefined.

Comment: I've created a [repository](https://github.com/lddubeau/requirejs-global-config) that illustrates the mechanism. I've created it by cutting-and-pasting the relevant code from my answer and creating a ``main.js`` that does the absolute minimum. The console shows the expected value for ``url``.